# Shell script - math operations and loops

Tags: mysql, bash, shell

I'm writing a sh file to run it via `cron` jobs, but I have no idea about shell script, I want to get the count of rows from `mysql` query then divide it by 200, **ceil** the result and start a loop from 0 to that amount.

After a long search, I wrote this line to get the count of rows from `mysql` query, and this works fine.

```
total=`mysql database -uuser -ppassword -s -N -e "SELECT count(id) as total FROM users"`
```

but all what I get from Google doesn't help me to complete my work, I tested something like "expr" and "let" methods for math operations, but I don't know why not working.

Even examples of loop I found on Google not working.

Can you help me with this script?

Comment: why?  I just guessing here, but have you read the man page for `split`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are using Bash.  Here is how you divide:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#    ^
#    |
#    |
#    --> This should be at the top of your script to make sure you run Bash

value=$((total / 200)) # total => value returned from mysql
for ((i = 0; i <= $value; i++)); do
    # your code here
done
```

Stackoverflow has an astounding number of examples.  I recommend you taking a look at Bash documentation here: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info.

Comment: Thank you for the hint,I added that first line and receive "not found error", so I contacted my hosting company and I knew that my first code was right but not working duo to security settings.

But as an important note, my code working now without that first line.

Comment: I will accept your answer for your help, the hint and for the working code. Thank you mate.